# Moving a file based on its type

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell and could use some help with this program, I just want to move files with a specific file type to a different directory.

```
$path = "C:\Users\jackb\Downloads"
$targetDir = "C:\Users\jackb\Pictures\MovedStuff"


Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.png, *.jpg, *.mp4, *.gif))

{

Move-Item $path $targetDir -Force

}
```

Comment: Change $path to $file, as that’s the variable you declared in the foreach loop. 

    Move-Item $file $targetDir

Comment: Ditto, but also you need to add parameter `-Recurse` to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet OR add `\*` to the path. Without that the `-Include` parameter does not work.